# How to use jbake-maven-plugin without using a pom.xml

Tags: maven, jbake

I have jbake based site with the normal structure with assets, content, templates. However, i would like to use the watch goal jbake-maven-plugin. But the jbake-sample seems to be a maven based java project. Could i use the jbake-maven-plugin without a pom.xml and without converting my structure to a java project.

jbake-maven-plugin - https://github.com/jbake-org/jbake-maven-plugin

jbake-sample - https://github.com/ingenieux/jbake-sample

Comment: The pom describes the configuration etc. and without a pom file it is not possilbe. JBake can be called from command line without any maven-plugin if you really like..

Comment: I got that :) But is there a possibility of using the maven plugin for content outside the src folder, the "content" folder.

Comment: If you like to really like to use the maven plugin you have to use a pom file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a *pom.xml*, **no** you can not use neither *Maven* nor any of the plugins as the project won't be interpreted as a *Maven*ized project.

Thus you will have to create at least a minimalistic project descriptor file (*pom.xml*) to get the basics working. (I'm talking from a pure *Maven* point of view as I'm little experienced with *jbake*).